# Android app size showing different on play store app than from play store website

Tags: google-play-store, apk

I have my app on play store. When I check the listing from the desktop my app size is shown as 8 MB, while if I check the same on the device's play store app, it is shown as 6.75 MB. I checked this on multiple devices and on each it is showing the same. I googled about the same but couldn't found anything relevant. Can someone please provide some information about this?

Update: This question has been marked as duplicate. Just to clarify, I am not talking about difference in sizes of installed app and the actual apk size. I am saying when I check google playstore on desktop, there my app size is displayed as 8 MB, while, when I check the same listing on playstore app in devices phone there it shows as 6.75 MB. I am not getting why google play store is showing two different size on desktop and in google play app.

Comment: Is your app installed on the device from whence you check at it via the Play Store?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman When my app was installed it was not showing its size on play store app, then I uninstalled it and retried, then it showed the app size.

Comment: Are you using same Google account on both website and Play Store app?

Comment: @Firelord Yes I am using same account

Comment: This generally happens due to syncing issues. We have noticed this phenomenon on several occassions. In our experience this gets rectified automatically after a while and both play store app and the web version will show the same size.